# IN clause with integers in sqlalchemy/psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Just a beginner with the python/postgres combo so forgive me if this is trivial.  I'm executing a raw SQL query with sqlalchemy along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE pk_table_id IN ()
```

For the example below I tried `self.ids` as a tuple containing string or integers as well as an array containing string or integers.  Either way it didn't work.

When I use this line:

```
my_connection.execute('SELECT * FROM public.table WHERE pk_table_id IN (%s)', self.ids)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

I ended up ditching SqlAlchemy for straight psycopg2, so I don't know if it applies 100%.  What I found out was that psycopg2 will correctly compile the IN clause if you pass it a tuple rather than an array/list.  I passed a tuple of integers and it worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks, this works very well. Instead of using `params=[list]` one should use `params=[tuple(list)]`

Comment: +1 - also see the docs: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [cur.mogrify](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adapt-tuple) method:

```
cur = my_connection.cursor()
cur.execute(cur.mogrify('SELECT * FROM public.table WHERE pk_table_id IN %s', (tuple(self.ids),)))
```

Comment: do not forget to close your cursor `cur.close()`

Comment: I don't think you need to use`cur.mogrify` inside the `cur.execute`, this works directly in the `execute` method

Comment: @Anentropic if it works then this is a new version. If you mean by works that you use the % sign, then you are introducing a security concern and I hope you don't mean that!

Answer (score 2):

The `%s` placeholder in `execute` expects a scalar, not a tuple.  You either need to replace it with `','.join(('%s',) * len(mytuple))`, or use string substitution instead!

Comment: Fixed the answer, because the original version would produce `'%,s,%,s,%,s'`.

Comment: It's not correct: single `%s` query expects sequence with single item.

Comment: That's the solution i used to solve my problem, thanks.
My usecase:
    ``tags_to_remove = set(['foo', 'bar'])``
    ``db.execute('DELETE FROM article_tags WHERE article_id = ? AND tag_name IN (%s)' % (', '.join(('?',) * len(tags_to_remove))), article_id, *tags_remove)``

Answer (score 2):

if your ids are in a list you can use list adaptation:

```
my_connection.execute('SELECT * FROM public.table WHERE pk_table_id = ANY(%s)', (self.ids,))
```

Taken from [lists-adaptation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#lists-adaptation)

Answer (score 0):

if self.ids is an array, you will have a problem doing the conversion within the execute statement. Instead, you should do it as a string operation before calling the execute statement.

Try this:

```
my_connection.execute('SELECT * FROM public.table WHERE pk_table_id IN (%s)' % 
                      ",".join(str(x) for x in self.ids))
```

Comment: Note: The given call to `join` would require the IDs in `self.ids` to be strings.

Comment: No, it would not. Python uses %s for all variable substitutions.

Comment: Sure, passing `int`s to `%s` string formatting parameters would work, but `str.join()` is not that liberal. Try `','.join(range(10))` in a Python shell.

Comment: No problem at all: `",".join([str(x) for x in range(10)])`

Comment: Your call to `join` in your answer assumes that the items in `self.ids` are strings, hence my original comment.

Comment: not when I use the list comprehension. They are all transformed into strings now.

Comment: [Warning: Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#sql-injection)

Comment: Just want to reiterate the above. This answer suggests an approach that the psycopg documentation goes to great lengths to admonish its users to never, ever do, as it creates a gaping security hole.

Comment: What is the security hole? It's only a security hole if self.ids comes from the user, not if you generate it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[`cur.execute(query, vars=None)`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) expects **variables** (emphasis on plural) to be passed to it.

When passing a single parameter that is [iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884259/4047679): a list, a string, or, in this case, a tuple, that parameter needs to be wrapped as a tuple otherwise the `execute` function interprets it as multiple parameters being passed, even though the query is only expecting one parameter, hence the error `not all arguments converted` (emphasis on the plural).

The general fix is to **always** do `cur.execute(query, vars=(var1,)`. It's helpful to specify the `vars` keyword to remind yourself the function is expecting multiple arguments.

The specific fix in this case is

```
my_connection.execute('SELECT * FROM public.table WHERE pk_table_id IN %s)', (self.ids,))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (via: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2)

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-list

> Note You can use a Python list as the argument of the IN operator
> using the PostgreSQL ANY operator.

```
ids = [10, 20, 30]
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = ANY(%s);", (ids,))
```

> Furthermore ANY can also work with empty lists, whereas IN () is a SQL
> syntax error.