# What are iterator, iterable, and iteration?

Tags: python, iterator, iteration, terminology, iterable

What are "iterable", "iterator", and "iteration" in Python? How are they defined?

---

<sub>See also: [How to build a basic iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151)</sub>

Answer (score 654, accepted):

**Iteration** is a general term for taking each item of something, one after another. Any time you use a loop, explicit or implicit, to go over a group of items, that is iteration.

In Python, **iterable** and **iterator** have specific meanings.

An **iterable** is an object that has an `__iter__` method which returns an **iterator**, or which defines a `__getitem__` method that can take sequential indexes starting from zero (and raises an `IndexError` when the indexes are no longer valid). So an **iterable** is an object that you can get an **iterator** from.

An **iterator** is an object with a `next` (Python 2) or `__next__` (Python 3) method.

Whenever you use a `for` loop, or `map`, or a list comprehension, etc. in Python, the `next` method is called automatically to get each item from the **iterator**, thus going through the process of **iteration**.

A good place to start learning would be the [iterators section of the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) and the [iterator types section of the standard types page](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types). After you understand the basics, try the [iterators section of the Functional Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/dev/howto/functional.html#iterators).

Comment: It confuses me a lot that anything with a `__getitem__` method is considered iterable, but any existing `__len__` method is completely ignored. Principle of least astonishment failing hard here...

Comment: Note that `collections.abc.AsyncIterator` tests for `__aiter__` and `__anext__` methods. This is a new addition in 3.6.

Comment: @jlh why would `__len__` be necessarily tied to iteration? How would knowing the length of something help you iterate over it?

Comment: @shadowtalker it would help to know which indexes are valid, so you know which indexes can be used with `__getitem__`.

Comment: @jlh it sounds like you are proposing a very opinionated dfeault behavior. Consider that `{'a': 'hi', 'b': 'bye'}` has length of 2, but cannot be indexed by 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: @shadowtalker. But a dict has an `__iter__` method. I think jlh is referring to objects that are iterable specifically because they define: "a `__getitem__` method that can take sequential indexes starting from zero".

Comment: @Rich You can define such a `__getitem__` without supporting the length protocol. `len` simply has nothing to do with iteration.

Comment: @chepner Yes. That's what jlh is saying they find odd. A different implementation of Iteration via `__getitem__` *could* check the `len` to see which numerical indices are valid, and jlh assumed that was how it *was* implemented ... till they found out it wasn't.

Comment: You don't need to know the upper limit, though. Call `__getitem__` until it raises an exception, then raise `StopIteration` in its place. `__len__` is ignored because it's not needed with `__getitem__` and not useful without it.

Comment: Might be worth noting that "iteration" has another sense when used as a countable noun: it means an individual time that a repeated statement is executed. For example *"on each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will complete 10 iterations"*.

Comment: how to understand the ` explicit or implicit` in your answer?

Answer (score 410):

Here's the explanation I use in teaching Python classes:

An ITERABLE is:

- anything that can be looped over (i.e. you can loop over a string or file) or
- anything that can appear on the right-side of a for-loop:   `for x in iterable: ...` or
- anything you can call with `iter()` that will return an ITERATOR:  `iter(obj)` or
- an object that defines `__iter__` that returns a fresh ITERATOR,
  or it may have a `__getitem__` method suitable for indexed lookup.

An ITERATOR is an object:

- with state that remembers where it is during iteration,
- with a `__next__` method that:

  - returns the next value in the iteration
  - updates the state to point at the next value
  - signals when it is done by raising `StopIteration`
- and that is **self-iterable** (meaning that it has an `__iter__` method that returns `self`).

Notes:

- The `__next__` method in Python 3 is spelt `next` in Python 2, and
- The builtin function `next()` calls that method on the object passed to it.

For example:

```
>>> s = 'cat'      # s is an ITERABLE
                   # s is a str object that is immutable
                   # s has no state
                   # s has a __getitem__() method 

>>> t = iter(s)    # t is an ITERATOR
                   # t has state (it starts by pointing at the "c"
                   # t has a next() method and an __iter__() method

>>> next(t)        # the next() function returns the next value and advances the state
'c'
>>> next(t)        # the next() function returns the next value and advances
'a'
>>> next(t)        # the next() function returns the next value and advances
't'
>>> next(t)        # next() raises StopIteration to signal that iteration is complete
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
StopIteration

>>> iter(t) is t   # the iterator is self-iterable
```

Comment: what do you mean by fresh iterator?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf "Fresh" as in "new and unconsumed" as opposed to "exhausted or partially consumed".  The idea is that a new iterator starts at the beginning, while a partially used iterator picks up where it left off.

Comment: Your 2nd, 3rd, and 4th bullets clearly indicate what you mean, in terms of specific python constructs or built-ins or method calls. But the 1st bullet ("anything that can be looped over") doesn't have that clarity. Also, the 1st bullet seems to have an overlap with the 2nd bullet, since the 2nd bullet is about `for` loops, and the 1st bullet is about "looping over". Could you pls address these?

Comment: Pls consider re-phrasing "anything your can call with `iter()`" as "anything you can pass to `iter()`"

Comment: What would be an example of an iterable  without `__iter__()` method? (with just a `__getitem__()`?)

Answer (score 126):

The above answers are great, but as most of what I've seen, don't stress the *distinction* enough for people like me.

Also, people tend to get "too Pythonic" by putting definitions like "X is an object that has `__foo__()` method" before.  Such definitions are correct--they are based on duck-typing philosophy, but the focus on methods tends to get between when trying to understand the concept in its simplicity.

So I add my version.

---

In natural language,

- **iteration** is the process of taking one element at a time in a row of elements.

In Python,

- **iterable** is an object that is, well, iterable, which simply put, means that
  it can be used in iteration, e.g. with a `for` loop.  How?  By using *iterator*.
  I'll explain below.
- ... while **iterator** is an object that defines *how to actually do* the
  iteration--specifically *what is the next* element.  That's why it must have
  `next()` method.

Iterators are themselves also iterable, with the distinction that their `__iter__()` method returns the same object (`self`), regardless of whether or not its items have been consumed by previous calls to `next()`.

---

So what does Python interpreter think when it sees `for x in obj:` statement?

> Look, a `for` loop.   Looks like a job for an iterator...  Let's get one. ...
>   There's this `obj` guy, so let's ask him.
>
> "Mr. `obj`, do you have your iterator?" (... calls `iter(obj)`, which calls
>   `obj.__iter__()`, which happily hands out a shiny new iterator `_i`.)
>
> OK, that was easy... Let's start iterating then. (`x = _i.next()` ... `x = _i.next()`...)

Since Mr. `obj` succeeded in this test (by having certain method returning a valid iterator), we reward him with adjective: you can now call him "iterable Mr. `obj`".

However, in simple cases, you don't normally benefit from having iterator and iterable separately.  So you define *only one* object, which is also its own iterator.  (Python does not really care that `_i` handed out by `obj` wasn't all that shiny, but just the `obj` itself.)

This is why in most examples I've seen (and what had been confusing me over and over),
you can see:

```
class IterableExample(object):

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        pass
```

instead of

```
class Iterator(object):
    def next(self):
        pass

class Iterable(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return Iterator()
```

There are cases, though, when you can benefit from having iterator separated from the iterable, such as when you want to have one row of items, but more "cursors".  For example when you want to work with "current" and "forthcoming" elements, you can have separate iterators for both.  Or multiple threads pulling from a huge list: each can have its own iterator to traverse over all items. See [@Raymond's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884501/835945) and [@glglgl's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884245/835945) answers above.

Imagine what you could do:

```
class SmartIterableExample(object):

    def create_iterator(self):
        # An amazingly powerful yet simple way to create arbitrary
        # iterator, utilizing object state (or not, if you are fan
        # of functional), magic and nuclear waste--no kittens hurt.
        pass    # don't forget to add the next() method

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.create_iterator()
```

Notes:

- I'll repeat again: *iterator is not iterable*.  Iterator cannot be used as
  a "source" in `for` loop.  What `for` loop primarily needs is `__iter__()`
  (that returns something with `next()`).
- Of course, `for` is not the only iteration loop, so above applies to some other
  constructs as well (`while`...).
- Iterator's `next()` can throw StopIteration to stop iteration.  Does not have to,
  though, it can iterate forever or use other means.
- In the above "thought process", `_i` does not really exist.  I've made up that name.
- There's a small change in Python 3.x: `next()` method (not the built-in) now
  must be called `__next__()`.  Yes, it should have been like that all along.
- You can also think of it like this: iterable has the data, iterator pulls the next
  item

*Disclaimer:* I'm not a developer of any Python interpreter, so I don't really know what the interpreter "thinks".  The musings above are solely demonstration of how I understand the topic from other explanations, experiments and real-life experience of a Python newbie.

Comment: This is great - but I'm still a little confused. I thought your yellow box was saying that a `for` loop needs an iterator ("Look, a for loop. Looks like a job for an iterator... Let's get one."). But then you say in the notes at the end that "Iterator cannot be used as a source in a `for` loop"...?

Comment: Why do you put just `pass` in the code for those `next` definitions? I'll assume you just mean that someone has to implement a way to get the next one, since next has to return something.

Comment: @nealmcb Yes, I think that's what past me meant.  (That's what [`pass` is for](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass), after all.)

Comment: @AloisMahdal Ahh, I hadn't seen that use before. When I see `pass`, I think it is there for syntactic reasons. I just ran across the answers at [ellipsis object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6189281/507544) which are quite interesting: you can use `...` to indicate a "todo later" block. `NotImplemented` is also available.

Comment: While I like that you're stressing the distinction between an iterator and an iterable, this answer contradicts itself. First you write, 'Iterators are themselves also iterable', (which matches what is written in [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)). But then later on you write: '*iterator is not iterable*. Iterator cannot be used as a "source" in `for` loop'. I get the point of your answer, and like it otherwise, but I think it would benefit from fixing this.

Answer (score 30):

An iterable is a object which has a `__iter__()` method. It can possibly iterated over several times, such as `list()`s and `tuple()`s.

An iterator is the object which iterates. It is returned by an `__iter__()` method, returns itself via its own `__iter__()` method and has a `next()` method (`__next__()` in 3.x).

Iteration is the process of calling this `next()` resp. `__next__()` until it raises `StopIteration`.

Example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3] # iterable
>>> b1 = iter(a) # iterator 1
>>> b2 = iter(a) # iterator 2, independent of b1
>>> next(b1)
1
>>> next(b1)
2
>>> next(b2) # start over, as it is the first call to b2
1
>>> next(b1)
3
>>> next(b1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> b1 = iter(a) # new one, start over
>>> next(b1)
1
```

Comment: So really it's just a object that passes through container's? were would this be useful?

Comment: Often, but not always. A generator, file or database cursor can only be iterated once and thus are their own iterators.

Comment: I guess b2 doesn't have to independent of b1 ? for this special case, it's independent, sure I can make it not independent but also a valid `Iterable`.

Comment: @Bin Yes. As and `Iterator` is always `Iterable` and is its own `Iterator`, two calls of `iter()` do not necessarily give two independent `Iterator`s.

Comment: Is every list iterable? Are sets iterable? tuples?...

Comment: @PatrickT All three: yes. Just try it out. `for i in [1,3,4,6]: print(i)` / `for i in {1,3,4,6}: print(i)` / `for i in (1,3,4,6): print(i)`. Also, have a look at the documentation resp. language specification.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure about sets, but I guess the iterator just makes up an order for a set on the spot (and perhaps it's not twice the same order...)

Comment: @PatrickT That even might depend on the Python version, and on the execution history (e. g. the object IDs/addresses, their type etc.). If you need the set to be ordered, see more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1653970/296974) about ordered sets.

Answer (score 11):

I don’t know if it helps anybody but I always like to visualize concepts in my head to better understand them. So as I have a little son I visualize iterable/iterator concept with bricks and white paper.

Suppose we are in the dark room and on the floor we have bricks for my son. Bricks of different size, color, does not matter now. Suppose we have 5 bricks like those. Those 5 bricks can be described as an **object** – let’s say ***bricks kit***. We can do many things with this bricks kit – can take one and then take second and then third, can change places of bricks, put first brick above the second. We can do many sorts of things with those. Therefore this bricks kit is an **iterable object** or **sequence** as we can go through each brick and do something with it. We can only do it like my little son – we can play with **one** brick **at a time**. So again I imagine myself this bricks kit to be an **iterable**.

Now remember that we are in the dark room. Or almost dark. The thing is that we don’t clearly see those bricks, what color they are, what shape etc. So even if we want to do something with them – aka **iterate through them** – we don’t really know what and how because it is too dark.

What we can do is near to first brick – as element of a bricks kit – we can put a piece of white fluorescent paper in order for us to see where the first brick-element is. And each time we take a brick from a kit, we replace the white piece of paper to a next brick in order to be able to see that in the dark room. This white piece of paper is nothing more than an **iterator**. It is an **object as well**. But an object with what we can work and play with elements of our iterable object – bricks kit.

That by the way explains my early mistake when I tried the following in an IDLE and got a TypeError:

```
 >>> X = [1,2,3,4,5]
 >>> next(X)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
      next(X)
 TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator
```

List X here was our bricks kit but NOT a white piece of paper. I needed to find an iterator first:

```
>>> X = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> bricks_kit = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> white_piece_of_paper = iter(bricks_kit)
>>> next(white_piece_of_paper)
1
>>> next(white_piece_of_paper)
2
>>>
```

Don’t know if it helps, but it helped me. If someone could confirm/correct visualization of the concept, I would be grateful. It would help me to learn more.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that you can get it much simpler than the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#iterators), however I'll try:

- **Iterable** is something that can be *iterated* over. In practice it *usually* means a *sequence* e.g. something that has a beginning and an end and some way to go through all the items  in it.
- You can think **Iterator** as a helper pseudo-method (or pseudo-attribute) that gives (or holds) the next (or first) item in the *iterable*. (In practice it is just an object that defines the method `next()`)
- **Iteration** is probably best explained by the Merriam-Webster [definition of the word](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iteration) :

> b : the repetition of a sequence of computer instructions a specified
>   number of times or until a condition is met — compare recursion

Answer (score 7):

> **Iterables** have a `__iter__` method that instantiates a new iterator every time.
>
> **Iterators** implement a `__next__` method that returns individual items, and a `__iter__` method that returns `self` .
>
> Therefore, iterators are also iterable, but iterables are not iterators.

Luciano Ramalho, Fluent Python.

Answer (score 6):

**Iterable**:- something that is iterable is iterable; like sequences like lists ,strings etc.
  Also it has either the `__getitem__` method or an `__iter__` method. Now if we use `iter()` function on that object, we'll get an iterator.

**Iterator**:- When we get the iterator object from the `iter()` function; we call `__next__()` method (in python3) or simply `next()` (in python2) to get elements one by one. This class or instance of this class is called an iterator.

**From docs:-**

The use of iterators pervades and unifies Python. Behind the scenes, the for statement calls `iter()` on the container object. The function returns an iterator object that defines the method `__next__()` which accesses elements in the container one at a time. When there are no more elements, `__next__()` raises a StopIteration exception which tells the for loop to terminate. You can call the `__next__()` method using the `next()` built-in function; this example shows how it all works:

```
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> it = iter(s)
>>> it
<iterator object at 0x00A1DB50>
>>> next(it)
'a'
>>> next(it)
'b'
>>> next(it)
'c'
>>> next(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    next(it)
StopIteration
```

Ex of a class:-

```
class Reverse:
    """Iterator for looping over a sequence backwards."""
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.index = len(data)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self.index == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.data[self.index]


>>> rev = Reverse('spam')
>>> iter(rev)
<__main__.Reverse object at 0x00A1DB50>
>>> for char in rev:
...     print(char)
...
m
a
p
s
```

Answer (score 5):

Iterators are objects that implement the **iter** and **next** methods. If those methods are defined, we can use for loop or comprehensions.

```
class Squares:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
        self.i = 0
        
    def __iter__(self):
        print('calling __iter__') # this will be called first and only once
        return self
    
    def __next__(self): 
        print('calling __next__') # this will be called for each iteration
        if self.i >= self.length:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            result = self.i ** 2
            self.i += 1
            return result
```

Iterators get exhausted. It means after you iterate over items, you cannot reiterate, you have to create a new object. Let's say you have a class, which holds the cities properties and you want to iterate over.

```
class Cities:
    def __init__(self):
        self._cities = ['Brooklyn', 'Manhattan', 'Prag', 'Madrid', 'London']
        self._index = 0
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self._index >= len(self._cities):
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            item = self._cities[self._index]
            self._index += 1
            return item
```

Instance of class Cities is an iterator. However if you want to reiterate over cities, you have to create a new object which is an expensive operation. You can separate the class into 2 classes: one returns cities and second returns an iterator which gets the cities as init param.

```
class Cities:
    def __init__(self):
        self._cities = ['New York', 'Newark', 'Istanbul', 'London']        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cities)



class CityIterator:
    def __init__(self, city_obj):
        # cities is an instance of Cities
        self._city_obj = city_obj
        self._index = 0
        
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self._index >= len(self._city_obj):
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            item = self._city_obj._cities[self._index]
            self._index += 1
            return item
```

Now if we need to create a new iterator, we do not have to create the data again, which is cities. We creates cities object and pass it to the iterator. But we are still doing extra work. We could implement this by creating only one class.

**Iterable** is a Python object that implements the **iterable protocol**. It requires only `__iter__()` that returns a new instance of iterator object.

```
class Cities:
    def __init__(self):
        self._cities = ['New York', 'Newark', 'Istanbul', 'Paris']
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cities)
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.CityIterator(self)
    
    class CityIterator:
        def __init__(self, city_obj):
            self._city_obj = city_obj
            self._index = 0

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def __next__(self):
            if self._index >= len(self._city_obj):
                raise StopIteration
            else:
                item = self._city_obj._cities[self._index]
                self._index += 1
                return item
```

Iterators has `__iter__` and `__next__`, iterables have `__iter__`, so we can say Iterators are also iterables but they are iterables that get exhausted. Iterables on the other hand never become exhausted
because they always return a new iterator that is then used to iterate

You notice that the main part of the iterable code is in the iterator, and the iterable itself is nothing more than an extra layer that allows us to create and access the iterator.

#### Iterating over an iterable

Python has a built function **iter()** which calls the `__iter__()`. When we iterate over an iterable, Python calls the **iter()** which returns an iterator, then it starts using `__next__()` of iterator to iterate over the data.

NOte that in the above example, Cities creates an iterable but it is not a sequence type, it means we cannot get a city by an index. To fix this we should just add `__get_item__` to the Cities class.

```
class Cities:
    def __init__(self):
        self._cities = ['New York', 'Newark', 'Budapest', 'Newcastle']
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cities)
    
    def __getitem__(self, s): # now a sequence type
        return self._cities[s]
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.CityIterator(self)
    
    class CityIterator:
        def __init__(self, city_obj):
            self._city_obj = city_obj
            self._index = 0

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def __next__(self):
            if self._index >= len(self._city_obj):
                raise StopIteration
            else:
                item = self._city_obj._cities[self._index]
                self._index += 1
                return item
```

Answer (score 3):

```
iterable = [1, 2] 

iterator = iter(iterable)

print(iterator.__next__())   

print(iterator.__next__())
```

so,

1. `iterable` is an **object** that can be **looped over**. e.g. list , string , tuple etc.
2. using the `iter` function on our `iterable` object will return an **iterator object.**
3. now this **iterator object** has method named `__next__` (in Python 3, or just `next` in Python 2) by which you can **access each element of iterable.**

so, 
    OUTPUT OF ABOVE CODE WILL BE:

1

2

Answer (score 3):

- An **iterable** is an object that has an **iter**() method which returns an iterator. It is something that can be looped over.
  Example : A list is iterable because we can loop over a list BUT is not an iterator
- An **iterator** is an object that you can get an iterator from. It is an object with a state so that it remember where it is during iteration

To see if the object has this method **iter**() we can use the below function.

```
ls = ['hello','bye']
print(dir(ls))
```

Output

```
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

As you can see has the **iter**() that's mean that is a iterable object, but doesn't contain the **next**() method which is a feature of the **iterator** object

Whenever you use a for loop or map or a list comprehension in Python the **next** method is called automatically to get each item from the iteration

Answer (score 2):

Before dealing with the  iterables and iterator the major factor that decide the iterable and iterator is sequence

Sequence: Sequence is the collection of data

Iterable: Iterable are the sequence type object that support `__iter__` method.

Iter method: Iter method take sequence as an input and create an object which is known as iterator

Iterator: Iterator are the object which call next method and transverse through the sequence. On calling the next method it returns the object that it traversed currently.

example:

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
```

x is a sequence which consists of collection of data

```
y=iter(x)
```

On calling `iter(x)` it returns a iterator only when the x object has iter method otherwise it raise an exception.If it returns iterator then y is assign like this:

```
y=[1,2,3,4]
```

As y is a iterator hence it support `next()` method

On calling next method it returns the individual elements of the list one by one.

After returning the last element of the sequence if we again call the next method it raise an StopIteration error

example:

```
>>> y.next()
1
>>> y.next()
2
>>> y.next()
3
>>> y.next()
4
>>> y.next()
StopIteration
```

Comment: Just an observation: y=iter(x) is not exactly y=[1,2,3,4] since y is now an iterator object. Perhaps you should add a comment to clarify that is not a list but an iterator object or change the representation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another view using `collections.abc`.  This view may be useful the second time around or later.

From `collections.abc` we can see the following hierarchy:

```py
builtins.object
    Iterable
        Iterator
            Generator
```

i.e. Generator is derived from Iterator is derived from Iterable is derived from the base object.

Hence,

- Every iterator is an iterable, but not every iterable is an iterator.  For example, `[1, 2, 3]` and `range(10)` are iterables, but not iterators.  `x = iter([1, 2, 3])` is an iterator *and* an iterable.
- A similar relationship exists between Iterator and Generator.
- Calling `iter()` on an iterator or a generator returns itself.  Thus, if `it` is an iterator, then `iter(it) is it` is True.
- Under the hood, a list comprehension like `[2 * x for x in nums]` or a for loop like `for x in nums:`, acts as though `iter()` is called on the iterable (`nums`) and then iterates over `nums` using that iterator.  Hence, all of the following are functionally equivalent (with, say, `nums=[1, 2, 3]`):

  - `for x in nums:`
  - `for x in iter(nums):`
  - `for x in iter(iter(nums))`:
  - `for x in iter(iter(iter(iter(iter(nums))))):`

Answer (score 0):

Other people already explained comprehensively, what is *iterable* and *iterator*, so I will try to do the same thing with **generators**.

IMHO the main problem for understanding generators is a confusing use of the word “generator”, because this word is used in *2 different meanings:*

1. as a **tool** for creating (generating) *iterators,*

   - in the form of a *function returning an iterator* (i.e. with the `yield` statement(s) in its body),
   - in the form of a *generator expression*
2. as a **result** of the use of that tool, i.e. the *resulting iterator.*
   (In this meaning a *generator* is a special form of an *iterator* — the word “generator” points out *how this iterator was created.*)

---

Generator as a *tool of the 1<sup>st</sup> type:*

```
In[2]: def my_generator():
  ...:     yield 100
  ...:     yield 200

In[3]: my_generator
```

> ```
> Out[3]: <function __main__.my_generator()>
> ```

```
In[4]: type(my_generator)
```

> ```
> Out[4]: function
> ```

Generator as a *result* (i.e. an *iterator*) of the use of this tool:

```
In[5]: my_iterator = my_generator()
In[6]: my_iterator
```

> ```
> Out[6]: <generator object my_generator at 0x00000000053EAE48>
> ```

```
In[7]: type(my_iterator)
```

> ```
> Out[7]: generator
> ```

---

Generator as a *tool of the 2<sup>nd</sup> type* — indistinguishable from the *resulting iterator* of this tool:

```
In[8]: my_gen_expression = (2 * i for i in (10, 20))
In[9]: my_gen_expression
```

> ```
> Out[9]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000000000542C048>
> ```

```
In[10]: type(my_gen_expression)
```

> ```
> Out[10]: generator
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For me, Python's [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) was most helpful for these questions, e.g. for iterable it says:

> An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of iterables include all sequence types (such as list, str, and tuple) and some non-sequence types like dict, file objects, and objects of any classes you define with an **iter**() method or with a **getitem**() method that implements Sequence semantics.

> Iterables can be used in a for loop and in many other places where a sequence is needed (zip(), map(), …). When an iterable object is passed as an argument to the built-in function iter(), it returns an iterator for the object. This iterator is good for one pass over the set of values. When using iterables, it is usually not necessary to call iter() or deal with iterator objects yourself. The for statement does that automatically for you, creating a temporary unnamed variable to hold the iterator for the duration of the loop. See also iterator, sequence, and generator.